# Are the click and focus events on a textbox in the wrong order in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, events

I like to have the value of a text box selected when it gets focus so I've got the following javascript in my Site.Master:

```
$("input:text").focus(function(){ $(this).select(); }
```

This (try it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/) works great in IE and Firefox but for some reason in Chrome, when you click on a text box you can see it for an instant selecting all the text and then it unselects it and puts the cursor at the position where you clicked.

I assume this is because whereas in other browsers the `click` event is raised before the `focus` event, in Chrome its the other way round?

Can anyone think of a way to achieve my goal in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small period for Chrome to react helps a lot: http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/2/

```
$(function(){
    $("input:text").focus(function(){ 
        var that = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            that.select();
        }, 13);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the default `mouseup()` event and you get the expected result like:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:text").focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });

    $("input:text").mouseup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/4/)

We are preventing the default `mouseup()` event here not `click()` event since the order of execution of the events is like:

1. focus
2. mouseup
3. click

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/7/) to demostrate that.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this is because whereas in other browsers the `click` event is raised before the `focus` event, in Chrome its the other way round?

Don't assume, **[test](http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/1/)**. (The same thing happens in Firefox, btw.)

You can work around the problem by using `setTimeout`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/6/)

```
$("input:text").focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.select()
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in chrome 28

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("input:text").focus(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
           $this.select();
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="select all of me!" />
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xVck/3/)